# Rhive query inserts multiple entries into Hive table for a single row insert when run via an Oozie job

Tags: r, hive, insert, oozie

I have an Oozie job which triggers a R script. The R script in turn runs a Hive query to insert a single row into a Hive table. But the problem is that there are 4 rows being inserted for a single insert statement when I run the job. However, if I run the Rscript alone without the Oozie job, it works fine and only a single row gets inserted into table.

**Please note:** Oozie job runs on Cloudera Hadoop Distribution.I suspect the problem to be in the BigData environment since the processing gets split between nodes. 
Below is the code that is present inside the R script.

```
library(RHive)
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_HOME"="/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop")
Sys.setenv("HIVE_HOME"="/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive")
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_CMD"="/etc/hadoop")
library(rhdfs)

rhive.init()
rhive.connect(host="10.223.99.33", port="10000", defaultFS="hdfs://10.223.69.37:8020")

rhive.execute("insert into table apphalo.errorlogtable values ('2017-08-21 15:00:08','Sampling','3657','3658','1','3','112')
```

To mitigate the issue, I tried writing the row to a csv file in HDFS and then in turn loading the csv file into the hive table. This also returned the same results(i.e. inserts 4 rows for a single row insert into hive table)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I myself found out the reason behind this. When you configure your hadoop environment, any script which is run in the hadoop environment is being run parallel on multiple servers in a distributed manner.

In this case, the script that I posted is being sent out to 3 servers (I have 3 servers in my configuration. It may vary if you have many) for distributed computing. Alas! That is the architecture of Hadoop. Due to the oozie job handling the script on multiple servers, the script is run 3 times, one for each server, due to which 3 inserts take place in the Hive table for every single run of the job.